# ERROR When Importing SQL File into MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to import an SQL file I have on a server and put it into the database.  But I keep failing and it gives me an error.

This is the command and error I get:

[image: Command and Error]

Comment: what is the actual name for the user in your database, surely you don't have a user literally called "username"

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot to change it to ubuntu when I snapped the picture, however the same error still comes up

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about granting MySQL access

Comment: ok, I'm sure I've seen this error before - have you googled for the message (and I'd add ubuntu as a keyword while googling)? It sounds to me like mysql settings for testing locally...

Comment: Yes I have tried to google and the answers have not helped me, the MySQL database is on Amazon's RDS service and I'm accessing it through PuTTy... if there's a better place for me to ask for help regarding this question please tell me where I can go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try logging into mysql first

```
mysql -p username 

enter your password:

mysql> source yourfile.sql;
```